# Constant data stored in texture memory: choose linear memory or 2D/3D arrays?

Tags: cuda, textures

My different kernels will be using some constant data. In order to optimize my code, I was considering using texture memory instead of constant memory, since each thread will be loading a different piece of data (the same for every block though).

For each thread, my data involves either a float (**M**), a size-3 vector of floats (**K**), or a 3-by-3 matrix of floats (**J**).

I have at least two choices:

- storing **M** in a 1D array, **K** in a 2D array and **J** in a 3D array.
- storing **M**, **K** and **J** in linear memory with some mapping.

Since the number of threads is very low (N = 32), which solution would be the best? Is it equivalent, or is `tex1Dfetch` faster than `tex2D` and `tex3D`? I do not need the features brought by CUDA arrays (hardware interpolation and so on), and memory limits are obviously not a problem.

Comment: Are your access patterns random? Which compute capability will you use?

Comment: No, basically thread `i` will access `M[i]`, `K[0..2][i]` etc. I am using CC 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Your access pattern for `M` is perfectly coalesced, so the global memory with the help of the cache hierarchy of compute capability devices > 2.x will give the best performance for that array.

You have the same access pattern in K and J, so, the accesses are also coalesced. So, there is no reason for not use the global memory and get the best performance

As you commented that *memory limits are obviously not a problem* I understand that the size of the arrays will be small, so you would expect a good behaviour of the cache hierarchy.

If you want to go one step forward, you could copy the `K` array to 1D texture memory and compare the performance of both approach.

Comment: Wouldn't `K[i][0..2]` be AoS instead? Memory would look like this: `K0x K0y K0z | K1x K1y K1z | K2x...`, so when loading the `x` coordinate of the vectors, memory access would be uncoalesced.

Comment: Another way to see this: if I use `tex1Dfetch` to get the `x`-th coordinate of **K** for a thread whose id is `tid` (with `K[0..2][tid]`), it would look like `tex1Dfetch(TEXTURE_REF_K, tid + x*NTHREADS)`. Your way would be `tex1Dfetch(TEXTURE_REF_K, tid*3 + x)`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Ups, you are right. I was mistaken. I should read the question more than twice.